# Changing Paypal Subscription Day

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I am currently using Paypal for subscription payments. Mostly it works fine but my problem is this:

If I am away for a week, how do I handle this? People pay mostly for the service the site provides and expect a certain amount of content added every day (or at least a weekly average amount). Therefore people shouldn't have to pay for access to the site during the time it is not being updated.

Previously I added the number of days I was away to the number of days of subscription everyone had remaining. But now there are people whose subscriptions are a few weeks into the future. Which is fine for me, but confused a lot of people.

To further confuse matters, some people pay weekly, some monthly, some annually. There is a 7 day (no Paypal needed) trial. People get their first 2 weeks in a subscription for a token amount. Some people don't pay a subscription and just pay for a week/month/etc as and then they want to.

The one-off payments and the free trial should be simple enough, I can add the days I'm away onto their account and they will know not to pay until it runs out. So it's mostly the subscription people that are the problem.

I see I can suspend payments, but I can't find any details of how this would work. If I imagine I am away from Monday until Thursday, I assume suspending payments for people wouldn't work - if someone's payment is due on Friday, I would have unsuspended the payments by then and their payment will go out as normal. If their payment was due on the Wednesday, the next time a payment will be taken is next Wednesday, so they will miss out on Friday (when I get back) until Wednesday when their next payment is taken. Or maybe suspending payments doesn't work like that.

An ideal situation would be to push user's payment forward until I'm back. I'd lengthen everyone's membership until the Friday and then payments would then start again from then - but I've not found any option to change subscription days.

I could cancel membership payments and then hope everyone signs back up, but I don't like that option.

Have I missed an option or is this one of those impossible situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The answer was very easy.

The best solution I've found is to add extra days to every ones subscription. Then just the recurring payment people, I need to lower their subscription payment. And then put it back to it's original value afterwards.

As a simple example. The subscription is £14 per week. I have 4 days off. Upon return I add 4 days to everyone (or a proportional amount (if they subscribe two days before I return, for example)). Then I make everyone's next subscription payment reduced by £8 (they subscription averages at £2 per day - for 4 days). Then after their reduced payment - make sure it goes back to normal.